# Evaluation by named ranges by JavaScript API does not work for certain formulas

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to rely on named range to evaluate a formula by JavaScript API. Although this approach works for most formulas, I found that the evaluated results are not correct for certains formulas such as certain formulas with `INDEX`.

I made [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chengtie/4d4d83407de404cd243043282fbd06e5) in Script Lab, part of which is as follows. In this sample, we define several named ranges with `=INDEX({1,2,3;4,5,6},{1;2},1)`, `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$8,3)`, `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$8,{3,4})` by JavaScript API. They work well in formulas in the workbook. However, their evaluated values (`[[1]]`, `null`, `null`) returned by JavaScript API are not correct in the code.

Does anyone know why it does not work for those formulas? Are there any other APIs we could use?

I have certain control over the formulas, for instance, I could transform them. Is it possible to transform those formulas to formulas on which JavaScript APIs for evaluation work?

Are there any workarounds?

```
async function test() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

    // setup cell values
    sheet.getRange("B3:B8").values = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]];
    sheet.getRange("F3").formulas = [["=name1"]]
    sheet.getRange("F7").formulas = [["=name2"]]
    sheet.getRange("F9").formulas = [["=name3"]]
    await context.sync();

    // clean names:
    var name1 = context.workbook.names.getItemOrNullObject("name1");
    var name2 = context.workbook.names.getItemOrNullObject("name2");
    var name3 = context.workbook.names.getItemOrNullObject("name3");
    name1.load();
    name2.load();
    name3.load();
    await context.sync();
    if (name1.value) name1.delete();
    if (name2.value) name2.delete();
    if (name3.value) name3.delete();
    await context.sync();

    // add names:
    context.workbook.names.add("name1", "=INDEX({1,2,3;4,5,6},{1;2},1)"); 
    context.workbook.names.add("name2", "=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$8,3)"); 
    context.workbook.names.add("name3", "=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$8,{3,4}"); 
    await context.sync();

    // show evaluated values:
    var name1 = context.workbook.names.getItemOrNullObject("name1");
    var name2 = context.workbook.names.getItemOrNullObject("name2");
    var name3 = context.workbook.names.getItemOrNullObject("name3");
    const avs1 = name1.arrayValues.load();
    const avs2 = name2.arrayValues.load();
    const avs3 = name3.arrayValues.load()
    await context.sync();
    console.log("name1: ", avs1.values)
    console.log("name2: ", avs2.values)
    console.log("name3: ", avs3.values)

    // show names:
    const namedItems = context.workbook.names.load();
    await context.sync();
    console.log("This worksheet contains " + namedItems.items.length + " named items.");
    for (let i = 0; i < namedItems.items.length; i++) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(namedItems.items[i])) + "\n";
    }
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you submitted the issue on GitHub too. We colleague has given out workaround towards your issue. If you have not checked it yet, please take a look at it.
Thanks.
ps: github issue link is https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2380

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).